# What's a C# regular expression that'll validate currency, float or integer?

Tags: c#, regex, numbers, currency

What is a regular expression suitable for C# that'll validate a number if it matches the following?

> ```
>  $1,000,000.150
>  $10000000.199
>  $10000 
>  1,000,000.150
>  100000.123
>  10000
> ```

Or the negative equivalents?

Comment: Do you need to use RegEx? Is the number you're looking for embedded within more text, or do you just want to be able to parse a string that might be in one of the above formats?

Comment: since when does valid currency has 3 digits after the period?

Comment: @csmba Why not? A cost per kg of a product you sell in tonnes might go to three decimal places.

Comment: I'm using a third party control with limited validation options - basically "number". this has no option for currency, so i need to use a regex. I can handle the various formats on the back end, so it'd be nice not to throw an error at the user when they input a currency value.

Comment: @csamba - exactly as matt says, these guys deal in large numbers, large quantities, 3 decimal places.

Comment: @[more than two digits after the period]: Have a look at the exchange rates between currencies. They usually have four decimal places. And it would be kind of bad if that wouldn't be a valid value ;)

Comment: I understand that other *currencies* do not exist, right? the world is spinning around dollar alone... ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use csmba's regex if you make one slight modification to it.

```
^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)$
```

Comment: cheers - csamba's appeared to work for me, is there a bug this mod takes care of?

Comment: marked as answer because it actually provided a working regex

Answer (score 5):

I think ssg is right. 
It's not a really good use of Regex, especially if your software has to deal with non-US centric data entry.

For instance, if the currency symbol is the Euro, or the Japanese Yen or the British Pound any of the other dozen currency symbols out there?

What about number formatting rules?

In the US you would enter `1,000,000.00` but in France, this should be `1.000.000,00`. Other countries allow spacing between digit-grouping...

If you use a straight Regex without taking the Culture into account, then you're never going to validate successfully unless you're 100% sure your software will never ever be used in a non-US centric context.

Answer (score 3):

```
^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(\.\d{1,3})?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{2})?)$
```

Comment: oops, spoke to soon, it seems to die on negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a problem with ssg's solution (or perhaps an MS bug!).

Running this:

```
float.TryParse("0,2",NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out num)
```

Returns true. Surely "0,2" isn't a valid currency value?

Comment: that would be .20 in France, mexico, spain, or any other latin derived country.  See the comments above on international formats.  Funny, however, that in specifying US you are still getting true.  That would be a bug if it is repeatable.

Comment: It does indeed appear to be an MS bug. Here are some of the combinations I tried in the Immediate Window:

float.TryParse("0,2",NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out num)
RETURNS true
float.TryParse("0,2",NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"), out num)
RETURNS true
float.TryParse("0..2",NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"), out num)
RETURNS false
float.TryParse("0.2",NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"), out num)
RETURNS true

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. The comma is merely a grouping separator, not a radix.
It's utterly logical that "0,2" is successfully parsed as 2. Likewise, "0,2.98" would be parsed as: 2.98

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with floats.  Eventually you will hit a case such as 0.01 represented as 0.00999999.  Strings or integers are better to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It may need some fine tuning to only allow for a single decimal point, but it does match your test cases. I hope this helps.

```
[$\d,.]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression for US currency
\$(\d)*\d
Matches $300,$12900
Non-Match $12900.00

Answer (score 0):

This regular Expression works for me:

```
'^[$]{0,1}([0-9]+[,]?[0-9]+|[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{3})*([,][0-9]+)?)$'
```

with switch

```
'^\${0,1}(\d+,?[0-9]+|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?)$'
```

it works for

- $1,000,000.150
- 10000000.199
- $10000
- 1,000,000.150
- 100000.123
- 10000