# How to validate integer and float input in an ASP.NET textbox

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am using the code below to validate integers and floats in ASP.NET, but if I do not enter decimal then it gives me an error.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAjaxFloat" runat="server" />
 <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" TargetControlID="txtAjaxFloat" FilterType="Custom, numbers" ValidChars="." runat="server" />
```

I also have the regular expression from *[What's a C# regular expression that'll validate currency, float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617826/whats-a-c-regular-expression-thatll-validate-currency-float-or-integer)*, but it's giving a validation error if I enter only one value after the decimal..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ControlValidators](http://devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=46).

For example (from the link)

```
<asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server"/>
<asp:RangeValidator id="valRange" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="textbox1"
    MaximumValue="12/31/1998"
    MinimumValue="1/1/1998"
    Type="Date"
    ErrorMessage="* The date must be between 1/1/1998 and 12/13/1998"
    Display="static">*</asp:RangeValidator>
>
```

The `Type` attribute can be one of "String", "Integer", "Double", "Date" or "Currency"

Comment: link is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Style="z-index: 103; left: 289px; position: absolute; top: 132px"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender
    ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1"
    runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TextBox2"
    ValidChars="0123456789.">
</cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator6"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TBHd"
    ValidationExpression="([0-9])[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Entry">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about plain simple parsing? E.g.

```
int i;
if (!int.TryParse(txtAjaxFloat.Text, out i))
   i = 0;

float f;
if (!float.TryParse(txtAjaxFloat.Text, out f))
   f = 0;
```

Where 0 is your default "could not validate" value.

Answer (score 0):

we can  use CompareValidator with Datatypecheck Operator to checkbox the datatype of the text in the textbox.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CValid" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Float value required." Operator="DataTypeCheck" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Providing just a piece of code without any comment is not the best practice of answer. Please add a couple of words to your code.