# textbox one with number only and another with comma in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text box in a form. One verifies for number only and another one for number and comma.

**1st case number only.**

```
function(textBoxObject) {
    var that = $(this),
    val = that.val();

    if (val === "" || isNaN(val)) {
      that.addClass("error");
    } else {
     that.removeClass("error");
    }
}
```

**2nd case number and comma.**

How do I handle another textbox which takes numbers and commas? And is it possible to add the logic in the first function itself?

Comment: You might need to take a look at [this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190312/validate-currency-amount-using-regular-expressions-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you treat 12,34 as illegal and 1,234 as legal. Then here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v02eo2ft/)

```
function checkNumberWithComma(textBox) {
    if ((textBox.value == 0 || textBox.value) && textBox.value.match(/^\d{0,3}(?:,\d{3})*$/)) {
        $(textBox).removeClass("error");
    }
    else {
        $(textBox).addClass("error");
    }
}
```

And the regular expression:

```
^       means start
\d{0,3} means 0-3 digits
(?:     means non-capturing group 
,
\d{3}   means 3 digits
)
*       means repeat for 0 or more times
$       means end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *.indexOf()* method.

something like...

```
if(val.indexOf(',') === -1) {
    ...your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use `if(val.match(/^(\d,?)*$/g))`

It will allow an empty string, numbers and numbers seperated by commas. It does allow commas at the end of the string, though.

So, `1,2,3,4`, `1234` and `1234,` all pass, but `,12,34` and `foo` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/OPLKRJ), I don't know exactly the behaviour you want but you can try something similar.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  function validateInput() {
      var that = $(this),
      val = that.val();
      if (that.attr('data-type') === 'number') {
        if (val === '' || isNaN(val)) that.addClass('error');
        else that.removeClass('error');
      }
      else {
        if (val.indexOf(',') === -1) that.addClass('error');
        else that.removeClass('error');
      }
  }

  $('input').change(validateInput);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label> Number
    <input type="text" data-type="number"/>
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label> Comma
    <input type="text"/>
  </label>
</div>
```