# Validating my money

Tags: c#, validation, numbers, currency

I am having some trouble validating a money input.  I have used some pointers from my other questions to write some better code.  The following is what I'm using to validate whether or not the input is money.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myTest1 = "$1,234.56";
    string myTest2 = "$1.00";
    string myTest3 = "$1000.01";
    string myTest4 = "$1,234,567.89";

    myIsMaybeMoneyValidator Miimv = new myIsMaybeMoneyValidator();

    bool myResult1 = Miimv.isMaybeMoney(myTest1);
    bool myResult2 = Miimv.isMaybeMoney(myTest2);
    bool myResult3 = Miimv.isMaybeMoney(myTest3);
    bool myResult4 = Miimv.isMaybeMoney(myTest4);
}

public bool isMaybeMoney(object theirMaybeMoney)
{
    string myMaybeMoney = theirMaybeMoney.ToString();

    if (myMaybeMoney.StartsWith("-"))
    {
        myMaybeMoney.Remove(0, 1);
    }

    if (!myMaybeMoney.StartsWith("$"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    myMaybeMoney.Remove(0, 1);

    string[] myMaybeMoneyStringArray = myMaybeMoney.Split('.');

    string myMaybeMoneyDollars = myMaybeMoneyStringArray[0];
    string myMaybeMoneyCents = myMaybeMoneyStringArray[1];

    if (!isDollars(myMaybeMoneyDollars))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!isCents(myMaybeMoneyCents))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private bool isDollars(string theirMaybeMoneyDollars)
{
    if (!isNumber(theirMaybeMoneyDollars))
        return false;

    try
    {
        int myMaybeDollars = Convert.ToInt32(theirMaybeMoneyDollars);

        if (myMaybeDollars < 1)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private bool isCents(string theirMaybeMoneyCents)
{
    if (!isNumber(theirMaybeMoneyCents))
        return false;

    try
    {
        int myMaybeCents = Convert.ToInt32(theirMaybeMoneyCents);

        if (myMaybeCents > 99)
            return false;
        if (myMaybeCents < 1)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private bool isNumber(object theirMaybeNumber)
{
    return Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(theirMaybeNumber);
}
```

The results are all not money, which is pretty confusing to me.

Comment: What is `myIsMaybeMoneyValidator`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Waiting for a regex solution... Also why arent you using regex I bet there are plenty of very good examples of them for USD.

Comment: You need to learn Regular Expressions

Comment: I retract my previous statement it seems like there is a builtin currency function for C# why use messy regex when C# has already handled it

Comment: RegEx could be the solution here..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617826/whats-a-c-sharp-regular-expression-thatll-validate-currency-float-or-integer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like there is a builtin validation for money in C#.

```
float num;
bool isValid = float.TryParse(str, 
NumberStyles.Currency,
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), // cached
out num);
```

FROM:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/617847/290822

Answer (score 1):

Try
`decimal.TryParse(myTest4, NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out myResult4)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
float value;
bool isMoney= float.TryParse(str, 
    NumberStyles.Currency,
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
    out value);
```

If you want to know what's wrong with your code, it's probably *Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(theirMaybeNumber);* Not handling the commas.

Comment: IsNumeric also returns True if Expression contains a valid numeric expression that begins with a + or - character or contains commas.